# Is it possible to modify the result of a GET request with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm on a website that is not mine, and an HTTP GET request is called onmouseover on a link. The result is a `<table>` which is removed onmouseout.

Is it possible for me to edit the contents of the `<table>` before it is called?

I have tried adding a second EventListener to the link but it only gets called before the `<table>` is created:

```
var matchupTable = document.getElementById('chessvs'),
matchupProfileLink = matchupTable.getElementsByTagName('a');

function getHoverProfile() {
    var i, currentLink;
    for (i = 0; i < matchupProfileLink.length; i += 1) {
        currentLink = matchupProfileLink[i];
        if (currentLink.innerHTML !== gk_uid && currentLink.title !== 'premium subscriber') {
            currentLink.addEventListener('mouseover',
                function hideHoverRank() {
                var hoverProfile = document.getElementsByTagName('table'),
                currentTable, i;
                for (i = 0; i < hoverProfile.length; i += 1) {
                currentTable = hoverProfile[i];
                console.log(currentTable);
                }
            }, false);
        }
    }
} 
getHoverProfile();
```

Comment: It sounds like you're saying the <div> is created when the GET request completes. Is that not the case?

Comment: The <div> containing the <table> is created when I mouseover the link, and then is removed when I mouseout. As far as I can tell in firebug, the GET also appears when I mouseover.

Comment: It sounds like you'd have to insert your behavior in between whatever code creates the table and whatever code runs the GET, which isn't going to be possible to time using the mouseover event. If there was an event handler that triggered off of updating the DOM you could use that, but that's not part of standard web behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The only table in your example is in `document`. You can do whatever you want with it. You can also try to unbind the original get-success handler on all anchors in chessvs.